# repeat function with parameter by settimeout inside itselft

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js, recursion

I need to iterate a function with its argument but got the recursion error

```
Error in mounted hook: "InternalError: too much recursion"
```

the function:

```
methods: {
    showSlides: function(n) {
        console.log(n);
        setTimeout(this.showSlides(n), 3000);
        //setTimeout(this.showSlides(n++), 3000);
    }
},
```

Comment: The first argument to `setTimeout` should be a function, not a function call.

Comment: i used it `setTimeout(function() {
            this.showSlides(n++);
        }, 2000)`  but got `TypeError: this.showSlides is not a function`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback

Comment: why did u close this question? did u check the mentioned link?

Comment: What's wrong with the link I gave? It explains why you have to use a function instead of a function call.

Comment: as i said i also called a function inside setTimeOut but returned definition error

Comment: `setTimeout(this.showSlides.bind(this, n+1), 3000);` should do the trick. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: @HamaBohel That's why I gave you a second link that explains how to fix that problem.

Comment: Thanks Niet fo your feedback, it didnt work, i dont know why that guy closed this question when there isnt a clear guid about it

Comment: try this, `methods: { showSlides(n) { setTimeout(() => { this.showSlides(n) }, 3000) } }`